# Add class from custom field into widget class

Tags: custom-field, widgets, sidebar

How would I add a class coming from a custom field to a widget?
I know I should put it somewhere into $before_widget ... in my case this is

```
'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s grid-33'.$color.'">',
```

I tried using $color and adding

```
global $post;
$color = get_post_meta($post->post_parent, 'bg_color', true );
```

above, but obviously I am not doing it the right way since it doesn't spit out the color class.

Comment: So you want to have the option to set different  background color for some widgets when viewing single posts?

Comment: You can not define widget class from postmeta on register widget function. For before_widget argument, you can try to put a placeholder class which you will be replaced on the widget() method on your widget class. Like: `'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s I_WILL_REPLACE_YOU_LATER">'` , and later on widget method after extracting $arguments, `$before_widget = str_replace('I_WILL_REPLACE_YOU_LATER', $color, $before_widget );` .

Comment: Hi Birgire, I want the wordpress editor to be able to change the background color of widgets using a dropdown within in the widget.

That's what I did Shazzad, I ended up using a slightly adjusted version of this:
http://ednailor.com/2011/01/24/adding-custom-css-classes-to-sidebar-widgets/